# AWS beanstalk application https config not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a load balancer configured beanstalk application running on node.js.

I have successfully configured https for the load balancer. I want communication between the load balancer and the beanstalk application to be done over https.

I have created a target group with port 443 and protocol HTTPS.  And configured the rule of my load balancer's https listernet to forward request to above target group. But the target group status is always unhealthy. The target group with port 80 and protocol http work fine though.

Can someone please help me with the reason behind it and how to overcome it. Please note - My load balancer has both http and https listeners enabled on port 80 and 443 repsectively.

Comment: show your target group setting and listener for `https`, unhealthy mean you are setting `443` for container side, on container side it should be `80` and LB port should be `443`

Comment: I tried to change the port of my target group to 80. This is the target group which gets default forwarding from my https listener. STill no success. HTTPS listener of LB  listens on port 443.

Comment: Can you post the screen shot of target group and listeners

Comment: https://imgur.com/AowVBjv - screenshot of listernet ..had to hide sensitive information.

Comment: https://imgur.com/lJWsHov - Link of my target settings in target group

Comment: In your last screen shot you set protocol to https, set this to http, you target group should contain http not https, only the listener will have this

Comment: Thats exactly my concern...basically we want our communication between load balancer and beanstalk app to be secure with https

Comment: Ssl should be terminated at load balancr level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding your image as a reference, as you see you see in the image, you set target port **80** but you have set the protocol **`https`**.

[image]

Change the protocol from **`https`** to **`http`**.

Do not worry about the communication between client and LB, it will be encrypted, the instance will receive decrypted traffic from LB.

> Thats exactly my concern...basically we want our communication between
>   load balancer and beanstalk app to be secure with https

LB and beanstalk both in the local network so the main concern is to secure client to server communication which LB does.

SSL terminates at LB level.

[image]

[https-load-balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-https-load-balancers.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Adiii. That makes completely sense. But unfortunately one of my requirements is to have communication between LB and EC2 to be over SSL.

Comment: Also, considering a scenario I do not have LB in between and I am directly hitting the Beanstalk URL ..how can I make it secure with SSL?

Comment: The best practice is to use SSL for client-server communication and use decreytp traffic between instance and LB, otherwise, it will create extra overhead to have ssl between LB and Ec2

Comment: " considering a scenario I do not have LB in-between", then you need to place SSL certificate in the instance itself, but I will not recommend that.  Your end-user will interact with LB not instance. so better to follow the above.

Comment: Even I agree with decrypt traffic thing..but unfortunately my requirement is a bit different. Can you guide me on how to place a certificate in beanstalk instance..because our configuration doesn't have a key pair to login into the ec2 instance. We have to get it done via .ebextension folder it seems. Can you guide me with that?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html may this help.